# Show progress in dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, progress

I have a process that takes a long time, and I want a window to show the progress.  But, I can't figure how to display the progress.

Here's the code:

```
if (procced)
{
    // the wpf windows :
    myLectureFichierEnCour = new LectureFichierEnCour(_myTandemLTEclass);
    myLectureFichierEnCour.Show();

    bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgw.DoWork += startThreadProcessDataFromFileAndPutInDataSet;
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += threadProcessDataFromFileAndPutInDataSetCompleted;

    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

And:

```
private void startThreadProcessDataFromFileAndPutInDataSet(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    _myTandemLTEclass.processDataFromFileAndPutInDataSet(
        _strCompositeKey,_strHourToSecondConversion,_strDateField);
}
```

I can call `_myTandemLTEclass.processProgress` to get a hint of the progress.

Answer (score 6):

You should handle the `ProgressChanged` event and update the progress bar in your user interface there.

In the actual function that does the work (`DoWork` event handler), you'll call the `ReportProgress` method of the `BackgroundWorker` instance with an argument specifying the amount of task completed.

The [BackgroundWorker example in MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is a simple code snippet that does the job.

Comment: Don't forget to set the WorkerReportsProgress property to true on the backgroundworker

Answer (score 1):

Your backgroundWorker thread needs to handle the `DoWork` method and `ProgressChanged`.

You also need to make sure you turn on the `WorkerReportsProgress` flag to true (off by default).

See example code:

```
private void downloadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Start the download operation in the background.
    this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

    // Disable the button for the duration of the download.
    this.downloadButton.Enabled = false;

    // Once you have started the background thread you 
    // can exit the handler and the application will 
    // wait until the RunWorkerCompleted event is raised.

    // Or if you want to do something else in the main thread,
    // such as update a progress bar, you can do so in a loop 
    // while checking IsBusy to see if the background task is
    // still running.

    while (this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
        // Keep UI messages moving, so the form remains 
        // responsive during the asynchronous operation.
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```